# Why the difference in the rows count?

Tags: mysql

Hi I don't understand why my MYSQL is behaving strangely.

Here i want to know number of records present in the table **site_details** inorder to get this i have executed
    `select count(*) from site_details;`
I have got the result as

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     2024 |
+----------+
```

And then to verify again i have executed
   `mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM msp LIKE 'site_details'\G`
I have got result like

```
 *************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: site_details
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 1612
 Avg_row_length: 71
    Data_length: 114688
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 81920
      Data_free: 7340032
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2012-10-01 08:05:09
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Observe the count difference between the rows count for the two queries

and then without modifying my table i have again executed the same query 
     `mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM msp LIKE 'site_details'\G`
and strangely i have got the result like

```
 *************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: site_details
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 1934
 Avg_row_length: 59
    Data_length: 114688
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 81920
      Data_free: 7340032
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2012-10-01 08:05:09
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Observe the Rows column for the above queries I have got results like 2024 1612 1934

Why this is happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*)...
```

gives you the actual number of rows now

```
select count(1)...
```

gives the number of rows where the first column is not null

The others are database-dictionary-based metrics which are not updated in real time but are dependent upon statistics etc.

See here for info on `COUNT`:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

So if you want the exact number of rows - duplicates and all - *right now* (open transactions perhaps excepted, depending on the isaolation level), **use `COUNT(*)`.**

Answer (score 1):

From [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html)

> The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the
>   exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is
>   an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40
>   to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate
>   count.

So, it's a normal behavior for InnoDB databases